# Angular animation stagger not working properly

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

I have a little issue with new Angular 4.2 animations features (query, stagger).

**Expected behaviour**: when i click on `Toggle` button every `[animate-bar]` animates in order

**Result**: Only first `[animate-bar]` animates

Here's a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qaJpj4Maf0QobAv8bXe6?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to make some workaround for this. You can use animateChild and another animation.

```
trigger('listAnimation', [
    transition('* => *', [
        query('@slideIn', [
            stagger(30, [
                animateChild()
            ]),
        ], { optional: true })
    ]),
])
```

Here's a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/QWgiE4tYLN3O2Tnx1E7j?p=preview